# Обернуть начало текста в div до знака тире в тексте

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Добрый день, уважаемые знатоки.

Прошу у Вас помощи или совета.
Есть текст в котором начало предложения заканчивается знаком тире.
Сам вопрос. Как сделать так, чтобы само начало предложения в тексте, заканчивающееся знаком тире, поместить в div?
Понимаю что с помощью скрипта, но как начать?

Comment: >начало предложения заканчивается знаком тире

Это как? Что такое "начало предложения", которое чем-то заканчивается, как его отличить от любого другого фрагмента текста?

Comment: Это как чтобы начало предложения заканчивалось? Пример есть этого?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваше "*начало заканчивающегося предложения*", то смотрите такие варианты (хотя их можно придумать и больше):

```
var str = 'Проблемка - есть текст, в котором начало предложения, заканчивается знаком тире.';
// вариант 1
var symbPos = str.indexOf('-');
console.log('<div>' + str.substring(0, symbPos) + '</div>' + str.substring(symbPos));
// вариант 2
var parts = str.split('-');
parts[0] = '<div>' + parts[0] + '</div>';
console.log(parts.join('-'));
```

В обоих случаях, на выходе получим:

```
<div>Проблемка </div>- есть текст, в котором начало предложения, заканчивается знаком тире.
```

Comment: Спасибо Deonis, за ответ.
Еще вопрос, а если объявленная переменная, является PHP переменной класса? 
Т. е. var str = '<?php $test; ?>';

Comment: Какой такой класс? После отработки PHP вы получите в JavaScript переменную `str` и ничего больше. Клиетская сторона про PHP вообще ничего не знает.

BTW, учитывайте, что в примере не тире, а дефис или знак "минус".

Comment: Да, уже понял, почитал. Спасибо.